# Can spring boot generate rest api document as the error page?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Is there a way that make Spring generate documents of all my rest APIs automatically and set it as the error page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Spring REST Docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-restdocs/docs/1.1.0.RELEASE/reference/html5/) is the tool to help you to produce documentation for your RESTful services that is accurate and readable.

An alternative is [swagger](http://swagger.io/), with the swagger annotion, it is eaiser to integrate with existing RESTful services and generated the swagger UI page.

Then [customize the spring boot error page](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-error-handling-custom-error-pages)